# Bulma limitations?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, frameworks, styles, bulma

I am trying to decide on a CSS framework for a basic portfolio website. I want to have some JS components that I can add with a separate library. It seems that people love Bulma but I am wondering what are the limitations give it is a "JS free" framework.

So far I have only used Bootstrap and I would like to try something new and preferably cleaner and easier to use.

Any insights and suggestions are welcomed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Bulma has most of the important things that you will need. It does lack some things, however. For example, Bulma doesn't have alerts, carousel, list group, etc. Bulma addresses this on their website (https://bulma.io/alternative-to-bootstrap/). Personally, I would say stick to bootstrap. It has a larger community (which means more stack overflow questions, documentation, etc.), and its color scheme is more professional.

Comment: Thanks @Jason C! I asked around and most people recommend sticking to Bootstrap as well.

Comment: I adopted bulma for a few projects, but am not happy. I am eagerly waiting for Bootstrap 5. They are removing the JQuery dependency, they provide scss support (Bulma uses the indented sass syntax), and their HTML is way simpler and more expressive (compare their form syntax).